# Is it possible for tourists to drive unhindered to the top of Mauna Kea on the big island of Hawaii?

Tags: driving, hawaii

Last year access to the top of Mauna Kea was blocked by protesters.  They were attempting to stop construction of a new telescope.  Does anyone know if regular access to the top has been re-opened?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe according to [Hawai'i magazine](https://www.hawaiimagazine.com/content/mauna-kea-access-road-has-reopened-public) in an article from January 2020

> In late December 2019, Harry Kim, mayor of Hawaiʻi County, struck a
> deal with protestors after ongoing negotiations to have the road
> cleared only for those wishing to visit the summit, however, no TMT
> construction materials would be allowed up. And on December 28th,
> 2019, the road was cleared of tents and protestors for the first time
> since its closing. This truce between protestors and government
> officials is expected to last until the end of February, after which
> negotiations will start up once again.

And then the [West Hawai'i Today](https://www.westhawaiitoday.com/2020/04/26/hawaii-news/despite-pandemic-some-continue-camping-on-maunakea/) article from April 2020 says

> Back in March, a camp that had stood for eight months in opposition to
> the proposed construction of the Thirty Meter Telescope on Maunakea
> was formally disbanded to ensure occupants’ safety as the pandemic
> intensified. However, a handful of people remain up there at any given
> time, along with a few abandoned tents and other detritus.
>
> ...
>
> When the stay-at-home order is lifted — ostensibly on April 30,
> although that date could well be pushed back — Wong-Wilson said camp
> occupants will return to dismantle the rest of the camp.

Suggesting that the road is open to tourists.

However for a definitive answer I'd call the [MAUNAKEA VISITOR INFORMATION STATION](http://www.ifa.hawaii.edu/info/vis/home.html)

Note that there are probably still COVID-19 restrictions in place, and that many sources say the that the last 5 miles of road to the actual summit require a true 4WD vehicle with a low range - and that using your rental car to get there will probably void your agreement. From the visitor center:

> Visitors are advised that only TRUE 4-wheel drive vehicles with LOW
> range may travel above the VIS.  About 200 yards beyond the station,
> the pavement ends and the next five miles are a steep graded-gravel
> road. Before proceeding visitors should consult their rental vehicle
> company or review their contract concerning visiting the summit of
> Maunakea.  Many rental companies do not allow their vehicles on the
> summit even if they are 4-wheel drive, and if anything were to happen
> to your vehicle you would potentiially be responsible for all towing
> charges and repairs, which can be thousands of dollars ($$$$).

Comment: I can confirm its fully open as of January 2021. Didn't see any signs of protests.